# Weird .hasOwnProperty behaviour

Tags: json, typescript, hasownproperty

In an effort to properly instantiate Typescript objects from data received over HTTP as JSON, I was exploring the possibility of using the `for..in` loop coupled with `.hasOwnProperty()` like so:

```
class User {
    private name: string;
    private age: number;

    constructor(data: JSON) {
        console.log('on constructor\ndata', data);

        for (var key in data) {
            console.log('key:', key);
            if (User.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log('User has key:', key);
                this[key] = data[key];
            }
        }
    }

    displayInfo(): string{
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Test";
button.onclick = () => {
    try{
        let json = JSON.parse('{"name": "Zorro","age": "24"}');
        let usr = new User(json);
        console.log(usr.displayInfo());
    }catch (error){
        alert(error);
    }

}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Using similar code in my project fails completely. That is expected as the   compiled JS code has no awareness of the private TS vars and so, `hasOwnProperty` is always `false`.

However, I was using the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), and running that code there produces the following output in the console:

```
on constructor
data Object {name: "Zorro", age: "24"}
key: name
User has key: name
key: age
{"name":"Zorro"}
```

As you can see, there are clearly some unexpected things happening here. The first key is recognized and the new User instance is initialized with the value from the JSON, yet that does not happen for the second key.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `User.hasOwnProperty` not `this.hasOwnProperty` or `data.hasOwnProperty`? Notice that `hasOwnProperty` is not a class reflection method, it's a on object method.

Comment: I agree with @Bergi - Calling `User` will call the class statically. While you could check prototyped properties that way, you would not be checking the properties of an object that has been instantiated.

Comment: @Bergi @Jim I do not want to check the properties of the object being instantiated, that would always return false as I call `hasOwnProperty` before actually setting the property values. That'd be the situation using `this`.
What I was trying to do is check if the key from the JSON exists in the class, not the instance, and only then set it to the value from the JSON. 
This was more of a fail-safe as since I control the JSON structure I don't actually need this check, but I experimented and got this result, which confused me

Comment: @TiagoVilaVerde: There is no class. `User` is the constructor, and it only has the properties `name`, `prototype`, and `length`.

Comment: You probably should simply do `this.name = data.name; this.age = data.age` and drop any enumerations or existence checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, you should be using `this.hasOwnProperty` instead of `User.hasOwnProperty`. And as you noticed, this code is busted anyway because the property declarations in the class don't actually create own properties on the object (they would need to be initialized for this to happen).

But why did you get a hit on the `name` key? The `User` object is a *constructor **function*** for your class. Functions do have a `name` property:

```
function fn() { }
console.log(fn.name); // prints 'fn'
```

They don't have an `age` property, of course.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor would of course just have to look like this, if you want to construct User instances from plain JavaScript objects:

```
constructor(data: any) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.age = data.age;
}
```